# VS 2008 won't let me create an Excel-Addin project

Tags: visual-studio-2008, vsto, office-2010

I have VS 2008 and Office 2010.  In VS2008, File->New->Office offers Excel2007 Add-in and Excel 2003 Add-in project types.  I chose Excel 2007, figuring that it would run on Excel 2010 anyway.  HOWEVER, VS 2008 immediately displays a pair of warnings:  "This project requires MS Excel 2007, but this app is not installed" and "The proj req the primary interaop assembly for Excel 2007, but this assmembly is not installed."  Upon building, I then get the message "You cannot debug or run this project because the required version of the MS Offce app is not installed.   I have not written or altered a single line of cose - just trying to compile the shell code created by the VS wizard.

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create the 2007 project it automatically adds the 2007 PIAs. You need the 2010 PIAs: http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=938fe8ad-583b-4bd7-a345-23250dc15855